# jquery conflict on wp-admin - wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wp-admin

I have problem with missing files in wp-admin. On live site everything is correct, 0 bugs but on wp-admin like you see it's messing jquery file.
pls help me...

[image: wp-admin screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Once, you need to check all the activated plugins one-by-one then you have found the plugins which shown the confliction.

Comment: I disabled all plugins but the problem persists